# Updating UI from background thread SWIFT

Tags: multithreading, macos, user-interface, swift

I'm using this code for background work:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, {
        // Some work in the background and updating UI too.
    });
```

However I was reading [here](http://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/) that we should use:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
// do some task
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // update some UI
}
}
```

when updating UI. 
My question is: In the code sample I am using the UI gets updated in the global queue and UI is updated without errors. What is the difference between the approach I am using, and the approach mentioned in the link above?

P.S: the code is executed on Mac OS X 10.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Thread Safety Summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) in the
"Threading Programming Guide" states:

> **Main Thread Only Classes**
>
> The following classes must be used only from the main thread of an
>   application.
>
> - `NSCell` and all of its descendants
> - `NSView` and all of its descendants.
>     For more information, see NSView Restrictions.

The only dispatch queue that is bound to the main thread is
the main queue that you get with `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

`dispatch_get_global_queue()` returns a global concurrent queue
which is *not* the main queue, and therefore may execute its work
on secondary threads. Therefore updating the UI from this queue
*may* work by chance, but it can also cause delayed UI updated,
non-working UI updates or crashes.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks. I'll mark your post as answer.