# very weird Xcode project bug?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I am attempting to integrate some `JSSAlertView`s within one of my ViewControllers, but for some odd reason, when I run my project, the alert views do not show. So to make sure it wasn't any error with coding, I created an exact pseudo project to replicate the ViewController of my original project, down to it's UI elements on the storyboard. I copied the exact code from my original project onto the new ViewController, ran it, and everything worked. Im stuck onto figuring out, why won't it work on my original project??

here is the logic i used:

```
@IBAction func resetPass(sender: AnyObject) {
        actview.hidden = false
        actview.startAnimating()

        PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(emailReset.text) {
            (success:Bool, error:NSError?) ->Void in

            if(success){

                let yesMessage = "Email was sent to you at \(self.emailReset.text)"

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    self.actview.stopAnimating()

                    JSSAlertView().success(self, title:"Great Success", text:yesMessage)

        }
    }

            if(error != nil){

                let errorMessage:String = error!.userInfo!["error"] as! String

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    self.actview.stopAnimating()

                    JSSAlertView().warning(self, title:"Woah There", text:errorMessage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I set a breakpoint on a call of one of the `JSSAlertView`'s , expanded the element in my console and got this :

[image]

Is this a memory management error and reason why they aren't visible? how do i fix this?

here is the Git if you want to check it out, its awesome: https://github.com/stakes/JSSAlertView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything with the UI needs to be done on the main thread, and you're calling the Parse function *on the background thread* (via `requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground`).

So to get your alerts to appear on the main thread, [you need to add a little GCD magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137380/updating-ui-from-background-thread-swift):

```
@IBAction func resetPass(sender: AnyObject) {

    actview.hidden = false
    actview.startAnimating()

    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(emailReset.text) {
        (success:Bool, error:NSError?) ->Void in

        if(success){
            self.actview.stopAnimating()

            let yesMessage = "Email was sent to you at \(self.emailReset.text)"
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.successMessage(yesMessage)
            }
        };

        if(error != nil){

            self.actview.stopAnimating()

            let errorMessage:String = error!.userInfo!["error"] as! String
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.failureMessage(errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See my addition of the "`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`" lines?

Comment: this didn't solve it. Still no appearance of the alert views. My thing is, if I had that exact code in a second view controller and the alert views appeared, do you still think it is a matter of my code or just a mishap in Xcode?

Comment: if you set an Xcode breakpoint on your two calls to `JSSAlertView`, do they *ever* hit?

Comment: wait a minute, check my edited answer, just discovered something after laying down a breakpoint

Comment: could you also get rid of the `var myAlert =` bits before those calls to `JSSAlertView`?  Part of me is worried that ARC is somehow releasing your alert before it even appears.

Comment: still nothing. you don't think those failed CGFloat values in the screenshot have anything to do with it?